# Can all git conflicts be resolved with a GUI tool

Tags: git, git-merge, meld

for eg `meld`
I want to know that do certain scenarios exist when you will have to resort to the text editor and `meld` just proves to be lacking something?

Comment: In most GUI tools you are basically editing your resulting file in some sort of text editor. As far as I can see, meld is not different. What actually do you mean to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is some scenarios. `mald` parses two files and tries to comapere every difference in them and give you a choice which one of two to use. But there could be hard parts to parse. And it gives you wrong lines for choice. You still can work in `meld` but it becomes complicated.

There is more advanced tools like `kdiff3` to make three way merge, they have better results in "understanding" differences. But even with it there could be such scenarios in wich the better way is to open both files it text editor and make things manually.

In such bad situation could be useful `git difftool` for comprasion current state of [file] with the state in the [branch].

```
git difftool [branch] -- [file]
```

Comment: Indeed, 3-way merge tools (also like `p4merge`) give a better understanding of other changes introduced by others because they show you diff with the common parent file (and give you a chance to understand what the others wanted to do and have done)